# Checking version of Applications installed in ~/Applications with unknown username

Tags: macos, command-line, firefox, regex, find

I'd like to check the version of Firefox through Apple Remote Desktop of all managed computers. I have written this, but it only checks for Firefox in /Applications

```
/bin/cat /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep -A 1 CFBundleShortVersionString | grep string | sed 's/[/]//' | sed 's/<string>//g'
```

For standard users Firefox auto update breaks if it is in /Applications so I instead have it installed in ~/Applications

I'd like to check that copy (if it exists), but I can't specify the path in the command since it is unique to each computer. For example:

> /Users/jon/Applications/Firefox.app
>
> /Users/arya/Applications/Firefox.app

Presumably I want to use find and pipe the result to my command. This should work for 10.6 through 10.8

Answer (score 0):

```
locate Firefox.app |grep "Firefox.app$"
```

should give you the exact location(s)

Comment: `locate` on OS X is uninitialized by default.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to us a shell script to get the list of user folders in /Users, and look through those in a loop.  Something like:

```
for i in $(ls /Users/ | grep -v Shared | grep -v Deleted)
do
    grep -A 1 CFBundleShortVersionString /Users/${i}/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep -A 1 CFBundleShortVersionString | grep string | sed 's/[/]//' | sed 's/<string>//g'
done
```